# Show Users who are in 10 KM radius from User's current location in PHP

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, maps

I have a requirement where I will get the Latitude and Longitude from an android app. Based on the that Latitude and Longitude received, I want to fetch other user's information from a database.

Users should be within 5 or 10 km radius with the given latitude and longitude. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Select users, where distance betwee the center of the radius is under 10 kms (google: how to compute distance latitude longitude) ?

Comment: i didn't get you.. Can you please explain in detail .?

Comment: So I understand here that you have a Database with users, and for each user you have the information of their locations. If you want to get users in the 10km radius specific circle, you have to compute the distance between all users and the center of your circle, and compare to 10km to see if are inside or outside; and so do thing with guys inside the radius

Comment: You could use a database with spatial extension such as PostgreSQL with PostGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is MySQL, and your users table is named users, and you want to find all users that are inside the radius of 10 kilometers, then using CodeIgniter:

```
// You would supply real latitude and longitude values here.
// I used a location in the southwestern United States.
$lat      = '34.770498';
$lng      = '-116.015625';
$distance = 10; // Kilometers

$this->load->database();

$query = $this->db->query(
    '
    SELECT 
        *,
        6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(RADIANS(? - ABS(users.latitude))), 2) + COS(RADIANS(?)) * COS(RADIANS(ABS(users.latitude))) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(? - users.longitude)), 2))) AS distance
    FROM users
    HAVING distance < ?
    ', 
    [
        $lat,
        $lat,
        $lng,
        $distance
    ] 
);

$local_users = $query->num_rows() > 0
    ? $query->result()
    : NULL;
```

For more information, check this out:
http://vinsol.com/blog/2011/08/30/geoproximity-search-with-mysql/

But even better would be to create a stored procedure that you can call. I do it like the following way on my website:

```
--
-- STORED PROCEDURE users_in_km_radius
-- 
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS users_in_km_radius $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `users_in_km_radius`( center_latitude float, center_longitude float, dist int, x_limit int, x_offset int )

BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

PREPARE ps FROM 'SELECT 
    u.*, 
    6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(RADIANS(? - ABS(u.latitude))), 2) + COS(RADIANS(?)) * COS(RADIANS(ABS(u.latitude))) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(? - u.longitude)), 2))) AS distance
FROM `users` u  
WHERE u.`longitude` between ? and ? 
AND u.`latitude` between ? and ? 
HAVING distance < ? 
ORDER BY distance';

set @center_latitude = center_latitude;
set @center_longitude = center_longitude;
set @dist = dist;
set @east = center_longitude-dist/abs(cos(radians(center_latitude))*111.04);
set @west = center_longitude+dist/abs(cos(radians(center_latitude))*111.04);
set @north = center_latitude-(dist/111.04);
set @south = center_latitude+(dist/111.04);

EXECUTE ps USING @center_latitude, @center_latitude, @center_longitude, @east, @west, @north, @south, @dist;
DROP PREPARE ps;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Using this is a little tricky in CodeIgniter:

```
$sql = '
    CALL users_in_km_radius( ?, ?, ? );
';

$query = $this->db->query( $sql, [ $lat, $long, $km ] ); 

if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $result = $query->result();

    mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);
    $query->free_result();
}
else
{
    $result = NULL;

    mysqli_next_result($this->db->conn_id);
    $query->free_result();
}
```